# Process ntoskrnl.exe CPU usage jumps from 1% to over 40% precisely when using I/O

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, charging, io, ntoskrnl.exe

the problem occurs with the following system.

Device: Lenovo Ideapad 730S - Windows version: 10.0.18362 Build 18362

So ntoskrnl.exe is running just fine as long as all the USB-C ports are left free. The exact moment I plug in my charger into one of the ports (doesn't matter which one I choose), ntoskrnl.exe starts using up about 40-50% of the CPU.

I've tried some basic troubleshooting (restart, checking for driver updates), and also the following after some research:

1. RestoreHealth via DISM
2. Windows Memory Diagnostic Run (no errors)

The problem is very bizarre to me as I couldn't find anyone who had the exact same problem with ntoskrnl.exe, so I'd be very grateful for some help. Of course I'm happy to provide more details if necessary.

Comment: Does CPU stay high?  I see this upon plugging in device, but CPU drops right back. Lenovo but not Ideapad.

Comment: @John Yes, it stays like that for a good while. However after another restart I've noticed it's just a short spike, as it is in your case. I'll leave the question up for another day and edit if the problem is fixed for good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem disappeared. I guess RestoreHealth helped after all.